# How to prevent renaming of dynamic type in dotfuscator

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I'm having problems when using renaming in dotfuscator, unexpected behavior occurs when not excluding dynamic type (runtime) how can I exclude all methods and fields..etc that uses dynamic type using regex?

sample methods:

```
 public static bool IsPropertyExist(dynamic obj, string property)
        {
            return ((IDictionary<string, object>)obj).ContainsKey(property);
        }

private dynamic GetResult(string jobData, dynamic data)
{
....
}
```

Comment: Either by the dotfuscator configuration file or by the `ObfuscationAttribute` in your code.

Comment: thanks but there's a tons of methods that has a dynamic in it's signature, how can i do it via regex?